# Transparency of subtitles in Vista / Windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I implemented the EVR renderer into a player of mine to deal with bad resizing quality on Windows Vista+ and came to problems...

I have subtitle overlay problems with the EVR:

[try to see what i'm talking about](http://marino.boletus.hr/3dpee.zip) - you must set the EVR in options.

I used this to apply a 32bit alpha bitmap onto VMR9, using a DirectX surface:

```
private void SetVRM9MixerSettings(int width, int height, int lines)
        {
            int hr = 0;
            VMR9AlphaBitmap alphaBmp;               

            // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters for using a Direct3D surface
            alphaBmp = new VMR9AlphaBitmap();
            alphaBmp.dwFlags = VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.EntireDDS | VMR9AlphaBitmapFlags.FilterMode;

            // on unmanagedSurface the bitmap was drawn with transparency
            alphaBmp.pDDS = unmanagedSurface;
            alphaBmp.rDest = GetDestRectangle(width, height, lines);
            alphaBmp.fAlpha = 1.0f;
            alphaBmp.dwFilterMode = VMRMixerPrefs.BiLinearFiltering;

            // for anaglyph half SBS
            if (FrameMode == Mars.FrameMode.HalfSideBySide)
            {
                alphaBmp.rDest.left /= 2;
                alphaBmp.rDest.right /= 2;
            }

            // Set Alpha Bitmap Parameters
            hr = mixerBitmap.SetAlphaBitmap(ref alphaBmp);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        }
```

Now however the project MediaFoundation.NET doesnt have the alphaBmp.pDDS pointer to set, so I cannot use a directdraw surface and need to use GDI (IF SOMEONE HAS A METHOD TO DO THIS IT WOULD BE COOL). But with GDI I cannot use 32bit alpha Bitmaps for true transparency - I only get 1 bit transparency with this approach:

```
 private void SetEVRMixerSettings(int width, int height, int subtitleLines)
        {
            MFVideoAlphaBitmap alphaBmp = new MFVideoAlphaBitmap();

            //alphaBitmap is a 32bit semitransparent Bitmap
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(alphaBitmap);

            // get pointer to needed objects
            IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
            IntPtr memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            IntPtr hBitmap = alphaBitmap.GetHbitmap();
            IntPtr hOld = SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);

            alphaBmp.GetBitmapFromDC = true;
            alphaBmp.stru = memDC;
            alphaBmp.paras = new MFVideoAlphaBitmapParams();
            alphaBmp.paras.dwFlags = MFVideoAlphaBitmapFlags.Alpha | MFVideoAlphaBitmapFlags.SrcColorKey | MFVideoAlphaBitmapFlags.DestRect;

            // calculate destination rectangle
            MFVideoNormalizedRect mfNRect = new MFVideoNormalizedRect();
            NormalizedRect nRect = GetDestRectangle(width, height, subtitleLines);

            mfNRect.top = nRect.top;
            mfNRect.left = nRect.left;
            mfNRect.right = nRect.right;
            mfNRect.bottom = nRect.bottom;

            // used when viewing half side by side anaglyph video that is stretched to full width
            if (FrameMode == Mars.FrameMode.HalfSideBySide)
            {
                mfNRect.left /= 2;
                mfNRect.right /= 2;
            } 

            alphaBmp.paras.nrcDest = mfNRect;

            // calculate source rectangle (full subtitle bitmap)
            MFRect rcSrc = new MFRect();
            rcSrc.bottom = alphaBitmap.Height;
            rcSrc.right = alphaBitmap.Width;
            rcSrc.top = 0;
            rcSrc.left = 0;

            alphaBmp.paras.rcSrc = rcSrc;

            // apply 1-bit transparency 
            System.Drawing.Color colorKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            alphaBmp.paras.clrSrcKey = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(colorKey);

            // 90% visible
            alphaBmp.paras.fAlpha = 0.9F;

            // set the bitmap to the evr mixer
            evrMixerBitmap.SetAlphaBitmap(alphaBmp);

            // cleanup
            SelectObject(memDC, hOld);
            DeleteDC(memDC);
            g.ReleaseHdc();

        }
```

So the questions are:

- How to use a DirectDraw surface to mix bitmaps on the EVR video 
  or
- How to mix a semi transparent bitmap without DirectDraw?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer the second question...

Alpha blending is rather simple task.
Assume that alpha is in the range from 0.0 - 1.0, where 0.0 means fully transparent and 1.0 represents a fully opaque color.

```
R_result = R_Source * alpha + R_destination * (1.0 - alpha)
```

Since we don't really need floats here, we can switch alpha to a 0-255 range.

```
R_result = ( R_Source * alpha + R_destination * (255 - alpha) ) >> 8
```

You can optimize it further... it's up to you.
Of course, same applies for G and B.

Comment: Thanks for the effort natko, but unfortunately this would require fetching the frame data locally on the CPU, and alpha blending on the CPU itself, for full HD video this literally eats the CPU. The result of the second snippet is a bitmap that gets sent to the EVR mixer and it blends the bitmap onto the video frame on the GPU.

Comment: Since you will be blending only the subtitle area, CPU load will not be noticeably higher. That even applies for the old and slow single core CPUs. Anyway, RGB color space is kind of a bad choice. In full frame operations CPU load can be considerably cut down by using some of the YUV color formats. Some of the 16-bit formats or even 12-bit planar formats are some kind of a standard for such purpose while picture quality remains the same.